# JAVA clone() copy object to other class objects

Tags: java

I want to ask you how can i copy firstClass objects to secondClass objects?

Is this possible to figure it out by using clone()?

The situation looks like this:

I have a class f.x. firstClass. And I need to clone firstClass objects to secondClass objects (and these cloned objects must be stored into array)

Thanks

EDITED:

sorry for a little information. But my task looks like this:

Write a Garage class whose objects can hold up to some number of Vehicle objects in an
array. Make Garage a Cloneable type, and write a proper clone method for it. Write a Garage.main
method to test it.

Comment: Would you like value copy or pointers are fine?

Comment: what do `firstClass` and `secondClass` look like? does one inherit from another?

Comment: I have edited my post for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?!

```
class Foo{
  private String bar;
  public Object clone(){
    Foo f=new Foo();
    f.setBar(this.bar);
    //filling and copy the f attributes
    guys.add(f);
  }
   ///
   private final static List<Foo> guys=new ArrayList<>();
   ///
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By convention, [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) method and its overrides should always return an object of the original type.

> x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()

So it should be impossible to create an object of different type if `clone()` is properly implemented and used.

Answer (score 3):

It's not cloning. If you have two unrelated classes, the best you can do is write a constructor for SecondClass that takes FirstClass object as an argument and writes all the values into the proper fields:

```
public SecondClass (FirstClass source){
  this.valueA = source.getValueA();
  this.valueB = source.getBValue();
  this.valueC = source.getProperCValue();
  ...
}
```